# TSQL Parse XML document

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've an XML which i want to parse in SQL server. this XML has list of games and list of rule associated with each game. I want the output as

```
        GameID  RuleID  RuleType    IsSelected
        380      16       0          TRUE
        380      19       0          FALSE
        380      17       0          FALSE
        382      16       0          FALSE
        382      19       0          TRUE
        382      17       0          TRUE
```

I'm using below mentioned query to get the output but my game id is getting repeated for all the element of rule list associated with each game.

```
SELECT 
    Game.value('GameID[1]','INT') AS GameID
    ,Game.value('IsSelected[1]','bit') AS GameSelected
    ,Rule1.value('(./RuleID/text())[1]','Int') AS RuleID                             
FROM @x.nodes('GameWorld/GameList/Game') TEMPTABLE(Game) 
OUTER APPLY
Game.nodes('//RuleList/Rule') AS Rules(Rule1)
```

XML document is as mentioned below. This document contains the list of all games and each game has an rule list associated with it.

```
<GameWorld xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
  <GameList> 
    <Game> 
      <GameID>380</GameID>  
      <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>  
      <RuleList> 
        <Rule> 
          <RuleID>16</RuleID>  
          <RuleType>0</RuleType>  
          <IsSelected>true</IsSelected> 
        </Rule>  
        <Rule> 
          <RuleID>19</RuleID>  
          <RuleType>0</RuleType>  
          <IsSelected>false</IsSelected> 
        </Rule>  
        <Rule> 
          <RuleID>17</RuleID>  
          <RuleType>0</RuleType>  
          <IsSelected>false</IsSelected> 
        </Rule> 
      </RuleList> 
    </Game>  
    <Game> 
      <GameID>381</GameID>  
      <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>  
      <RuleList> 
        <Rule> 
          <RuleID>16</RuleID>  
          <RuleType>0</RuleType>  
          <IsSelected>true</IsSelected> 
        </Rule>  
        <Rule> 
          <RuleID>19</RuleID>  
          <RuleType>0</RuleType>  
          <IsSelected>false</IsSelected> 
        </Rule>  
        <Rule> 
          <RuleID>17</RuleID>  
          <RuleType>0</RuleType>  
          <IsSelected>false</IsSelected> 
        </Rule> 
      </RuleList> 
    </Game> 
  </GameList> 
</GameWorld>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is because you didn't use `.` before `//` in the context where you want the XPath/XQuery to be relative, i.e here `Game.nodes('//RuleList/Rule')`. Try this way instead :

```
SELECT 
    Game.value('GameID[1]','INT') AS GameID
    ,Rule1.value('RuleID[1]','Int') AS RuleID                             
    ,Rule1.value('RuleType[1]','Int') AS RuleType  
    ,Rule1.value('IsSelected[1]','bit') AS IsSelected
FROM @x.nodes('GameWorld/GameList/Game') TEMPTABLE(Game) 
OUTER APPLY
Game.nodes('./RuleList/Rule') AS Rules(Rule1)
```

**<kbd>[`sqlfiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7183)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
| GameID | RuleID | RuleType | IsSelected |
|--------|--------|----------|------------|
|    380 |     16 |        0 |       true |
|    380 |     19 |        0 |      false |
|    380 |     17 |        0 |      false |
|    381 |     16 |        0 |       true |
|    381 |     19 |        0 |      false |
|    381 |     17 |        0 |      false |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Game.value('GameID[1]','INT') AS GameID,
    Rule1.value('RuleID[1]','Int') AS RuleID,
    Rule1.value('RuleType[1]','Int') AS RuleType,
    Rule1.value('IsSelected[1]','varchar(5)') AS IsSelected
FROM @x.nodes('GameWorld/GameList/Game') TEMPTABLE(Game) 
OUTER APPLY
Game.nodes('//RuleList/Rule') AS Rules(Rule1)
```